# Markdown - call a result from a table or a list in the text

Tags: r, r-markdown

Here is an example of what I'm trying to do. I would like to call in the text a result from a table itself coming from a random computation.

````
---
title: "Régression logistique"
subtitle: "Analyse quantitative II"
author: 
- name: ""
- affiliation: 
date: "TP 4"
output: 
  html_document: 
    toc: yes
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

```{r message=FALSE} 
bystander <- data.frame(reaction = c(rep(0, 30), rep(1, 30)),
                        age.victime = c(rep(5, 5),rep(85, 5),rep(7, 5),rep(35, 5),rep(45, 5),rep(50, 5)),
                        sexe.victime = c(rep(0, 20), rep(1, 10), rep(0, 10), rep(1, 20)),
                        nbrpers = c(11:40, 0:29),
                        statutse = c(rep(4, 30), rep(18, 30)))
 
#install.packages("caret")
library(caret)
# install.packages("lmtest")
library(lmtest)
#install.packages("pscl")
library(pscl)
#install.packages("e1071")
library(e1071)
```

```{r}
Train <- createDataPartition(bystander$reaction, p=0.8, list=FALSE)
training <- bystander[ Train, ]
testing <- bystander[ -Train, ]
training$reaction <- as.factor (training$reaction)
model_fit <- train(reaction ~ age.victime + sexe.victime + nbrepers + statutse, data=training, method="glm")
testing$reaction <- as.factor (testing$reaction)
pred <- predict(model_fit, newdata=testing)
confusionMatrix(data=pred, testing$reaction)
```

We obtain a an accuracy of `r confusionMatrix(data=pred, testing$reaction)`.
````

I just want the Accuracy from the overall in the confusionMatrix. Is there a way to call only this result because my trial is not working there (pretty logical, it's a list), like in latex when you can reference your results and call it later.

Thank's in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve your desired result assign the result of calling `caret::confusionMatrix` to variable. Afterwards you could access the `Accuracy` in an inline chunk like so:

````
---
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

```{r}
library(caret)
```

```{r}
conf_mat <- caret::confusionMatrix(iris$Species, sample(iris$Species))
```

We obtain an accuracy of `r conf_mat$overall[["Accuracy"]]`.
````

[image]